# Prompting when redirecting content of script to remote machine

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection

I have simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":u:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    u)
      USER="${OPTARG}"
    ;;
    \?)
      echo "Unknown flag has been used: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

stty -echo
read -p "New password for user ${USER}: " USER_PWD
stty echo

mysql -uroot -p -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${USER}; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO '${USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${USER_PWD}'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

I would like to use it on another machine without copying it there. So I'm doing:

```
cat myscript.sh | ssh myserver bash -s - -u some_user
```

However it doesn't prompt me for passwords, instead it outputs me only an error:

> stty: standard input: Invalid argument Enter password: ERROR 1045
>   (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   NO)

What I'm doing wrong? Is it impossible to being prompted when redirecting script like that?

**Added:**
I realized that my script have more problems (like using $USER variable, that is standard environmental variable), however my question really is about prompting. I reduced a problem to this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please write something: " SOME_VARIABLE
echo "Done"
```

And when I'm doing this:

```
cat test.sh | ssh user@server bash -s
```

It just echoes "Done", and doesn't let me to input anything on "read". Is it normal and why is that?

Comment: How about: `cat myscript.sh | ssh some_user@myserver bash -s -`

Comment: @Ketan Same story. :/

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any permission to run query from remote machine with root priviliage, your error said it.

Comment: But I can login to this machine and login to mysql as root without any problems. How is it different from above command?

Comment: `ERROR 1045 (28000)` said it.

Comment: how do you login? via mysql?

Comment: Everything is visible in cited code. I'm logging through SSH and trying to run commands from redirected content of script. One of those commands queries mysql, however instead of asking me for password, it just fails.

Comment: wow, be sure you have permission problem from mysql, your mysql configured for localhost. modify it.

Comment: you should grant for remote host to root user or your users.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but those commands are running on remote server, so I'm actually logging in from "localhost" from mysql point of view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13134/discussion-between-mohsen-pahlevanzadeh-and-lukasz-zaroda)